# Storybook autodocs feature in Vue files

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, storybook

I have a Vue 3 component in my Storybook 7.4 project. We use a composite API with "setup", like `<script lang="ts" setup>`. I want to use the "autodocs" feature described in the [Storybook doc](https://storybook.js.org/docs/vue/writing-docs/autodocs). Unfortunately, there is no example how to do it with the "setup" option there. Here is an example file:

```js
<template>
  <q-btn @click="emit('click')">
    <template v-slot:default>
      <div v-if="props.label">{{ props.label }}</div>
    </template>
  </q-btn>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
const props = defineProps({
  /**
   * This is the only working autodocs.
   */
  label: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
});

/**
 * It doesn't appear anywhere.
 */
const emit = defineEmits(['click']);
</script>

<style></style>
```

The only working JDoc is in the `defineProps`. I've tried adding comments here and there, but to no avail. Is there a way to use the autodocs feature in such files? Or any other suitable way? I don't want to write MDX, it seems to me very complex.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still using the option api with JS and only the top comment is part of the docs text in the story.

```
<script>
/**
 * BaseShinyBadge.vue shows a fancy badge / tag with a shiny star.
 * The shine can be toggled.
 *
 */
export default {
  name: 'BaseShinyBadge',
  props: {
    text: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    isSmall: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    showShine: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true,
    },
  },
  ...
  </script>
```

If you're using TS you could change your story to end as tsx and change the docs like described here:

https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-docs/autodocs#write-a-custom-template